# List the file and files versions in a particular snapshot of the iceberg

Tags: apache, snapshot, apache-iceberg

I want to list the file and files versions in a particular snapshot of the iceberg.

I used the version-travel queries, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM iceberg_table FOR VERSION AS OF 949530903748831860.
```

However, this lists all the versions of the file until the snapshot '949530903748831860'. I only want the file and file version present in snapshot '949530903748831860'.

Is there an SQL query to list only the file and file versions in a particular snapshot?